# As well to use controller inside another controller Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have two entities: users, announcements

Eaach user can publish the announcements.

I creted controller `AnnouncemetController`, where there is method class: `my()`, that returns notes for current user.

Also I have controller `ProfileController` that represent current profile user, where I need to show all announcements of user.

For this I tried to reuse controller `AnnouncemetController` inside `ProfileController` and call public method `my()`.

use App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementController;

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
      $my = new AnnouncementController();
      $my->my();
}
```

Is it well to use such?

Comment: Yes. I'd have done a bit differently. I will have used static method instead of non static and only thing I will have to write is: AnnouncementController::my();

Comment: I have two ways, create custom library Announcements or use method mentioned above. What will say professionals?

Comment: Also I think the best Idea is to use Model functions for specific user object to get it's announcements

Comment: Do you mean to create repeatedly method `my()` in ProfileController calling model?

Comment: No. To create method my() in User model and get like this:
$user->my();

Comment: For this I have separated model Announcements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Laravel controller maps a uri to an action.  In your example, you are using a controller to access data, so this is not the "right thing to do".

Instead use model methods to access the data.